# Callbacks and listeners ; MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, callback, awt, listeners

I'm trying to write a project with listeners, I've got my buttons working where they change the color, now i need my mouseLIsteners to print text of what the mouse is doing. for example:"Mouse has entered the yellow area, mouse has exited the yellow area, mouse has clicked in/ released yellow area, etc."
I have them implemented but nothing is working to get text to print out. Here's my code:

```
          import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class SwingLab
{

 // frame properties
 private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400; private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 // Instantiate a frame (the main window)
 JFrame frame = new JFrame();

 // The buttons (one for each color)
 final JButton bRed = new JButton("Red");
 JButton bYellow = new JButton("Yellow");
 JButton bBlue = new JButton("Blue");


 // Here we create a panel consisting of other panels (layed out in a
 // Grid) to support the buttons and "Art" instance

 final JPanel container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
 final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));
 final JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(3,1) );

 // An instance of a special class for you to play with (Art is defined
 // below)
 Art artBox=new Art();
 panel.add(artBox);

 // add the buttons to the panel
 buttonPanel.add(bRed);
 buttonPanel.add(bYellow);
 buttonPanel.add(bBlue);

 // put the panels together and add them to the frame
 container.add(panel);
 container.add(buttonPanel);
 frame.add(container);


 /* YOUR CODE GOES HERE */

 // declare your listener classes and add them to the buttons
 // here.
 // you are going to call addActionListener and
 // addMouseListener for each button
 // you want to deal with the JPanel named "panel" declared
 // above


 /*  END YOUR CODE */
 class RedButtonListener implements ActionListener, MouseListener

 {

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)

 {
 panel.setBackground(Color.RED);  
}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    bRed.addMouseListener(this);
     addMouseListener(this);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: Your code does not show your problem, other than that you have a lot of unnecessary redundancy, but again, this is not the cause of your bug. For us to help, you need to show enough code so that we can understand your problem, but not too much code as to overwhelm us with too much code that is not related to the problem at hand. Best would be if you could take time to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm new to java so that's probably why the redundancy. The problem is i have the listeners and events implemented but when I write System.out.println("The mouse has entered the yellow area") in the entered event, i have no texg

Comment: How are we to guess what might be the matter, if we don't see how you use your listeners, how you add them to your GUI? For example, nowhere do I see `addMouseListener(...)`. So where is it? In fact, **are** you adding any MouseListeners to anything?

Comment: I implemented the mouse listener to the class, so do i addMouseListener to each class?

Comment: Don't ask -- try! You've got a computer programming laboratory at your fingertips, so use it. Experiment, play, write code, run it, change it, push it to the limit and then go beyond, find out what works what doesn't work. Trust me, you're not going to blow up your computer, you're not going to bring on doom and damnation from the effort. For simple questions that can be answered by testing, don't ask us here -- find out for yourself. That's what learning and what programming is all about!

Answer (score 6):

An XxxxListener won't work unless you add it to something, unless it actually listens to something. For a MouseListener to react, it needs to be added to the listened to component via `someComponent.addMouseListener(myMouseListener)`. You will want to read the tutorial on listeners to get the fine details. First Google hit for `Java Swing MouseListener Tutorial`: [MouseListener Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

My main criticism of your question is that you're asking how to do something without first trying it, and sorry, but that is not how you will ever learn to program. There are tutorials available for this, and you've got a computer programming laboratory at your fingertips, so use it. Experiment, play, write code, run it, change it, push it to the limit and then go beyond, find out what works what doesn't work. Trust me, you're not going to blow up your computer, you're not going to bring on doom and damnation from the effort. For simple questions that can be answered by testing, don't ask us here -- find out for yourself. That's what learning and what programming is all about.

---

**Edit**

OK, you're adding your MouseListener **inside** of the MouseListener, which won't work. Why not add it in your class's constructor or some other init or set up method?  Also, your compiler will complain because your class that implements the MouseListener doesn't implement all the methods of the MouseListener interface, and that's not allowed (unless the class is abstract, which isn't what you want). So give it the rest of the MouseListener methods.

For example:

```
public class Foo extends JPanel {
   private JButton button = new JButton("Button");

   public Foo() {
      MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
      button.addActionListener(myListener);
      button.addMouseListener(myListener);

      add(button);
   }
```

Where

```
class MyListener implements MouseListener, ActionListener { 
     //.....  bunch of code here
}
```

Comment: I've been trying it all day and I'm getting closer to turning it in and this is the last thing I can't quite get. i read the tutorial earlier, and i've gotten this far by trying things but I'm just stuck. I can't seem to find a non-erroneous location to add.Mouselistener. I get an error every time and even when i phrase it like the tutorial i have no text

Comment: @ThomasNorman: if you're getting an error in your attempt, shouldn't you be showing this to us? How can we guess what you might be doing wrong otherwise?

Comment: @ThomasNorman: please post a small compilable and runnable program, or the closest you can come to this, as I mentioned in my first comment to your question, an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ThomasNorman: OK, you're adding your MouseListener **inside** of the MouseListener, which won't work. Why not add it in your class's constructor or some other init or set up method? Also, your compiler will complain because your class that implements the MouseListener doesn't implement all the methods of the MouseListener interface, and that's not allowed (unless the class is abstract, which isn't what you want). So give it the rest of the MouseListener methods.

Comment: @ThomasNorman: chit, your instructor's code comments ***tell*** you where you should be adding your listeners!! It's a good idea to read these comments *critically* to not ignore them.

Comment: Ok thank you. i'm going to use some of this info and keep working on it. I just have to figure out how to declare the classes for listeners and I'll be good.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding the listener only as an `ActionListener` so the methods that are implemented from that interface are working, but you have not added it as a `MouseListener`, so it will not receive callbacks for those events. But I agree with HoverCraft, you will learn nothing from your professor handing you code to tweak and us doing it for you. Actually, if you want to learn Swing, you should implement this whole program yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things wrong with your program.  First, you're not updating the widgets from the EDT, you need to put the entire contents of your main() into an invokeLater runnable.

Second, you need to define your listeners and then install them onto the buttons before they are displayed on the screen, not inside the listeners themselves.  The following program will toggle the colour when the button is clicked, and change the button text when the mouse exits and enters the button.

I've used MouseAdapter instead of mouseListener because it already has default, do-nothing, methods defined for all of the required methods of MouseListener.  So the code gets a little less cluttered:

```
    package swing;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class testFrame {

    public static void showFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLocation(500, 500);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        final JButton button = new JButton("Test");
        button.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(80, 30));
        button.setSize(80, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            boolean colourToggle = false;

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                button.setText("Mouse Out");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                button.setText("Mouse In");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (colourToggle) {
                    button.setBackground(new Color(100, 200, 100));
                } else {
                    button.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 150));
                }
                colourToggle = !colourToggle;
            }
        });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                showFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```